How to configure Dockerized Laravel Setup for Vite?
My goal is to Dockerize Laravel + Vite + React.js with Inertia.js for Development. I can get the app to run, but it has no Hot Module Replacement (HMR) and loads the pages like SSR pages and not quickly like SPA pages.
Assumption:
Vite might not be running correctly
Behaviour:
localhost:8000 shows the app correctly but without HMR and SPA-Behaviour
localhost:5173 shows the default page for vite+laravel
This is the base Dockerfile:
# Use the official PHP image as a base
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Install Composer 2.2
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --version=2.2.0 --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www

# Install Laravel dependencies
RUN composer install

RUN npm install

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000 5173
CMD ["sh", "-c", "php-fpm & npm run dev"]

This is the docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: laravel_app
    container_name: laravel_app
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - laravel
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - APP_DEBUG=true
      - APP_KEY=${APP_KEY}
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=laravel
      - DB_USERNAME=laravel
      - DB_PASSWORD=laravel

  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: laravel_web
    #restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - laravel
    depends_on:
      - app

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: laravel_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravel
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

volumes:
  dbdata:
  
networks:
  laravel:
    driver: bridge

This is the nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location /_vite/ {
        proxy_pass http://app:5173;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

This is the vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.jsx',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react({}),
    ],
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 5173,
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    },
});

